# Can't view changes of converting image to gray color gradually in a pictureBox at every single "for" loop (at run time) C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I know that "for loop" is very fast to process a job that you want , and it is fast according to the processor's speed.
Look at this code :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Bitmap bufferImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image); //just take the size from this -pictureBox1- will use an image 2000*1200
        //###############################################################################################
        int pixelValue = 0;
        int w = pictureBox1.Image.Width; //2000 pixel
        int h = pictureBox1.Image.Height; //1200 pixel

        for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 <= h; loop1++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = loop1 + "";

            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 <= w; loop2++)
            {
                textBox2.Text = loop2 + "";

                pixelValue = bufferImage.GetPixel(loop1, loop2).R;//color value
                bufferImage.SetPixel(loop1, loop2, Color.FromArgb(pixelValue, pixelValue, pixelValue));// Gray color.
                pictureBox1.Image = bufferImage;

            }
        }

    }
```

The project will wait few seconds (the textBoxes will still empty at this time , and pictureBox is without changes of gray color) , then when end of the loop entirely , the project will result in textBoxes and pictureBox this output below :

> output : textBox1 = 2000 , textBox2 = 1200 , pictureBox1 = image in gray color

Now : **1-** How can I view in every single loop the number ?
like 1-2-3-4-.....2000 fastly!
**(like using timer)**
To see what is the loop number now (at the run time) .
**2-** I want to convert the image in pictureBox to gray color gradually , to see the changes of the pictureBox.

Summary : I don't want to view the entirely result just when the two loops are end.

Comment: a) Get/SetPixel is terribly slow b) you are tying up the UI thread so it never comes around to display the changes c) calling Refresh  will enforce the display update and you will see just how slow the process actually is d) for a fast desaturation use a ColorMatrix

Comment: @TaW  That is a good answer with useful details . Thank you very much  .

Comment: You could use LockBits to access the image's backing byte array, though inn this case, as noted, ColorMatrix is probably the better solution. Also, consider using a separate thread for processing; and set up thread communication with your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Invalidate/Update it will "pause" execution of the function and forces it to update the UI instead of waiting till the end of the function.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bufferImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image); //just take the size from this -pictureBox1- will use an image 2000*1200
                                                                    //###############################################################################################
        int pixelValue = 0;
        int w = pictureBox1.Image.Width; //2000 pixel
        int h = pictureBox1.Image.Height; //1200 pixel

        for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < w; loop1++) // changed h to w
        {
            textBox1.Text = loop1 + "";
            textBox1.Invalidate();
            textBox1.Update();

            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < h; loop2++) // changed w to h
            {
                textBox2.Text = loop2 + "";
                textBox2.Invalidate();
                textBox2.Update();

                pixelValue = bufferImage.GetPixel(loop1, loop2).R;//color value
                bufferImage.SetPixel(loop1, loop2, Color.FromArgb(pixelValue, pixelValue, pixelValue));// Gray color.
                pictureBox1.Image = bufferImage;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                pictureBox1.Update();

            }

        }
    }
```